# What would happen if I overwrite the default flask-bootstrap head and scripts blocks?

Tags: python, flask, flask-bootstrap

I am learning to use flask-bootstrap extension in my app. But when I copied demo html codes from [getbootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com), it didn't work as the official site demonstrated. So I overwrote the head block and scripts block in my base template, then it works nicely.

Like this

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}

{% block head %}
    (my own head...)
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
    (my own scripts...)
{% endblock %}
```

Is it okay to overwrite `bootstrap/base.html`’s own head and scripts like this? What effects it will leave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will completely replace the base blocks.
To keep the existing blocks but add your own to them, you should use `super()`:

```
{% block head %}
    {{ super () }}
    (your head)
{% endblock %}
```

This will keep the originals... you can do the same in any other blocks.
See more here: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#super-blocks

Comment: I know this will completely replace the base blocks. What I want to confirm is that this "completely replacement" will not leave bad effects or    bugs. So, is it OK?

Comment: well, it depends on what's on `bootstrap/base.html`, just do it to see what happens. Initially I would say it would break some things....